# Converting OFL licensed Fonts to WOFF

Tags: fonts, software-recommendation, web-fonts, file-conversion

I would like to convert a font which uses the Open Font License to `WOFF` for use on a web site. My understanding is that this conversion probably contravenes the license. However, I have also read

> Please note that most WOFF conversion tools and online services do not meet the two requirements listed above

— https://theleagueof.github.io/licenses/ofl-faq.html (section 2.2)

This suggests that *some* tools do meet the requirements.

Can anybody suggest any software tools which meet this requirement? Preferably Open Source, and available on Linux or Macintosh.

Comment: Excellent question. I haven’t got an answer, but I would note that the preceding paragraph does say that you don’t have to adhere to those two requirements when converting to WOFF—you just have to change the font name if you don’t, because then it’s considered a Modified Version.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet _As far as I am aware_, this name needs to be changed internally as well, so that would still require some suitable software.

Comment: Yes, internally as well. You can do that quite easily with freeware like FontForge, though, so that in itself shouldn't be a major deterrent. It would be easier, of course, if you could find a converter that does actually adhere to the requirements, but don't let it stop you if you can't.

Comment: If you use fontlibrary.com to download SIL OFL fonts, many are also supplied in WOFF format in the zip file anyway.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of section:

> ### 2.2 Can I make and use WOFF (Web Open Font Format) versions of OFL fonts?
>
> 1. The original font data remains unchanged except for WOFF compression, and
> 2. WOFF-specific metadata is either omitted altogether or present and includes, unaltered, the contents of all equivalent metadata in the
>      original font.

So if you cannot find a conversion software that handles that then just change the name.

Because in that same section it reads

> "If the original font data or metadata is changed, or the
>   WOFF-specific metadata is incomplete, the font must be considered a
>   Modified Version, the OFL restrictions would apply and **the name of the
>   font must be changed"**

I recommend fontforge https://fontforge.github.io/en-US/
I read that it does work with WOFF but just change the name to something else and it will be seen as a modified font and you do not have to worry about the license.